# I need to migrate data from one old table to a new table by storing appropriate CityId instead CityName

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

I'm migrating data from one table to another table in SQL Server, In this process what I need to do is "I have 10 columns in old table one column is 'CityName' which is varchar and in the new table, I have a column 'CityId' which is an integer. And I have other table which has data about city id and names. I need store the appropriate cityId in new table instead of CityName. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside: It is typical to place cities within a hierarchy rather than floating on their own. Sure, everyone knows that Paris is in Texas, USA and Athens is in Georgia, USA. Tables for `Cities`, `States` (or `Provinces`, ...) and `Countries` are common. Each has a relation to the next larger entity, e.g. `Cities` would have `CityId`, `CityName`, `ProvinceId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should give you an idea, you need to inner join to your look up table to achieve this.

```
declare @t_cities table (Id int, City nvarchar(20))

insert into @t_cities 
    (Id, City)
values
    (1, 'London'),
    (2, 'Dublin'),
    (3, 'Paris'),
    (4, 'Berlin')    

declare @t table (City nvarchar(20), SomeColumn nvarchar(10))

insert into @t
values 
    ('London', 'AaaLon'),
    ('Paris', 'BeePar'),
    ('Berlin', 'CeeBer'),
    ('London', 'DeeLon'),
    ('Dublin', 'EeeDub')

declare @finalTable table (Id int, SomeColumn nvarchar(10))

insert into @finalTable
select c.Id, t.SomeColumn
from @t t
    join @t_cities c on c.City = t.City

select * from  @finalTable
```

**Output:**

```
Id  SomeColumn
1   AaaLon
3   BeePar
4   CeeBer
1   DeeLon
2   EeeDub
```

Comment: you will be able to upvote once reach 15 points (I helped you with that ;-) ), but you should be able to accept the answer I think, click "tick" under upvotes/downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to join the source table to the CityName field in the city information table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Destination (CityID, OtherStuff)
SELECT t1.CityID, t2.OtherStuff
FROM CityInformationTable t1
INNER JOIN SourceTable t2
ON t1.CityName = t2.CityName
```

Comment: Thank you, Russell Fox. It helped me.